# Multiple forms, instances and using them in a class. VB.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have an MDI Parentform and it has multiple forms which are declared as :

```
Partial Public Class Giriş

Private clients As thirdperson
Private suppliers As thirdperson
Private activecontrol As thirdperson
Private proposals As transactions
Private addproposal As addtransaction
private sales as transactions
private addsales as addtransation
Private products As products
...
...
```

I also have a dataworks sub which works as a class but i code it in form and also for each form as below :
'for example for pressing add new button

```
If ActiveControl Is **clients** Or ActiveControl Is **suppliers** Then
  activeform.dataworks (counter, "add new")
ElseIf ActiveControl Is products Then
  products.dataworks (counter, "add new")
ElseIf ActiveControl Is addproposal Then
  addproposal.dataworks (counter, "add new")
End If
```

i need a way to figure out how to use a vairble name for instance name. (I don't want to define each instance name everytime i just want to know if there is a way to use like below :
    'for example 
    dim formvariable as form

```
formvariable.dataworks(counter,"add new") --> just want to use this and assign the value for products, proposals vs to this variable.
```

is this possible?

Thanks for your help in advance. 
Sertac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way would be to develop an [Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e2e18x.aspx) that all of your Child Forms Implement.  That interface would have a dataworks() method.  Then you can cast the current mdichild to the interface type and run the method.  This would result in strongly typed coded that makes sense.

If you just want to hack your way through it, though, then attempt grab the dataworks() sub from the current mdichild using reflection and execute it like below:

```
    Dim frm As Form = Me.ActiveMdiChild
    If Not IsNothing(frm) Then
        Dim MI As Reflection.MethodInfo = frm.GetType.GetMethod("dataworks", Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase)
        If Not IsNothing(MI) Then
            MI.Invoke(frm, New Object() {counter, "add new"})
        End If
    End If
```

Here's a quick example of the Interface approach:

```
Public Interface Data

    Sub DataWorks(ByVal counter As Integer, ByVal msg As String)

End Interface
```

This is what thirdperson looks like implementing the interface:

```
Public Class thirdperson
    Implements Data

    Public Sub DataWorks(counter As Integer, msg As String) Implements Data.DataWorks
        Debug.Print(counter & ", " & msg)
    End Sub

End Class
```

All of your mdichild forms would have to be modified in a similar approach.

Then the code in the MdiParent would change to:

```
    Dim frm As Form = Me.ActiveMdiChild
    If TypeOf frm Is Data Then
        Dim D As Data = DirectCast(frm, Data)
        D.DataWorks(counter, "add new")
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But each dataworks in code has different bindingsources, tableadapter vs. so is it possible impeleng one dataworks sub to all my child forms?

Comment: Well, I assume each Form would do something **different** with the data (or at least display different parts of it)...so each form should have it's own dataworks() no?  What is typically done, however, is you create a **Data Access Layer** that all the Forms can access.  This can be as simple as putting your data access portions into a different `Class` and making them `Shared` so they can be accessed from the entire project.